# Chrome Extension: Geolocation in Google Maps in IFRAME within Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, geolocation

I think, that Geolocation doesn't work within IFRAME in popup.
Can anyone think about reason?

Steps to reproduce:

- Create chrome extension with `permissions: ["geolocation"]`
- Create page on server with Google Maps and Geoplugin enabled
- In popup action create IFRAME linking to this page

I would expect that I will get popup notification to enable geolocation, this does not happen.

Either I would expect this to work, if I enable geolocation when I open this page in separate window, it should work within IFRAME in extension, but neither this does work.

**CHROMIUM BUGS**
According to Rob W. recommendation, I've filed bug report to Chromium Project.
Link to Issue Tracker: 
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=119682

Comment: Maybe you can paste your code to jsFiddle or Gist so anyone who want to help will not need to create all out of nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions are only applied to the content located **within the extension's scope**, i.e. content from `chrome-extension://..extensionidhere../`.

An external page in the popup window is not treated as a part of the extension. Therefore, permissions of your extension does not affect the framed page.

Instead of including an external page within the frame, you'd better host the page inside your extension, or load the content using `XMLHttpRequest`. Chrome extensions can fetch cross-origin AJAX requests, so this is a decent solution.

Comment: He said 'I would expect that I will get popup notification to enable geolocation, this does not happen.' - so I think he understands execution scope.

Comment: I have just tested the feature. Regardless of the `geolocation` API preference ("Allow always"), the API does not work when the frame's content is from a **different origin than the chrome extension** (the `--disable-web-security`](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-web-security) flag doesn't work either). A work-around is mentioned in my answer. I recommend to **file a bug report at http://new.crbug.com/** + a [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/W3cJ3/1/show/). Also: [Current list](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?q=geolocation).

Comment: @RobW thanks Rob, I'll file a bug report, as it looks like, it's the only thing I can do for now. I'll update this thread later, if this bug will be resolved in Chromium project development.

Comment: @MarekSebera When you file a bug, can you add a link here? So that future readers can check whether the bug is fixed or not.

Comment: @RobW Link is on bottom of question. Thanks for your assistance.